# UIlabel line break not working when using PhosphateInline font

Tags: ios, uilabel, xcode8, line-breaks, custom-font

when i use custom font (http://fontzone.net/font-details/phosphateinline)
in my UIlabel (i have configured it properly in Xcode), it won`t change line even though i have set the number of line to 0 and Word wrap for the line break, i also set the height >= 30 and i have set the text to uppercase because PhosphateInline only works with uppercase letter. 
But still, the line break is not working ([http://imgur.com/a/cvRFp](https://imgur.com/a/cvRFp)), it overwrites the existing word. When i try the other font, line break is working properly.

What is the problem ? In Android, it doesn't have any problem like that, but in Xcode, line break doesn't work properly

Comment: Please post code to reproduce.

Comment: i set it up in Storyboard, not by code for this setting:
number of lines: 0 , Line break: word wrap, height>=30